# Create a identical "random" float based on multiple data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, hash

I'm working on a game (Unity) and I need to create a random float value (between 0 and 1) based on multiple `int` and/or `float`.

I think it'll be more easy to manually create a single string for the function, but maybe it could accept a list of `int` and/or `float`.

**Example of result:**

- `"[5-91]-52-1"` > `0.158756..`

**Important points:**

- The distribution of results (between 0 and 1) must be equals (don't want 90% of results between 0.45 and 0.55)
- Asking 2 times for the same string **must** return the exact same result (even if I reload the app, or start it on different computers, ..)
- Results have no need to be unique.

**Bonus Point:**

- Sometime I need that close similar string return close result, but not everytime. It's possible for "random generation" to handle a boolean with this feature ?

Comment: Use the hashcode of the string as the seed for a `Random` object maybe?

Comment: Look like a good solution thanks. I'm checking that. I'm just concerne about creating a new `Random` object and setup a new seed for every request, isn't too heavy ? Instead of setup a seed and request multiple numbers on it (`normal` use)

Comment: Creating multiple instances isn't heavy; it just typically leads to the scenario you are actually aiming for (replicating sequences); which is usually undesirable

Comment: Okay thank a lot. Last question (close to the bonus point), what's the distribution of the hashcode and the connection it have with seed setup ? Ex: If I'm stating every string with `[` it'll affect result distibution or not at all ? (Can you also create a reply to set as answer)

Comment: If you need the result to be identical even after restart of the program (or between multiple instances of the program), you shoud be aware that [Object.GetHashCode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_GetHashCode) guarantees to return identical values only inside original app-domain, otherwise you may need to create your own implementation of hashing function that returns stable results even between app-domains.

Comment: @Ňuf The most important point on this function is to create the exact **same** result whatever the instance of app or computer asking for :/

Comment: Look like `Unity Random.seed` don't have this problem

Answer (score 4):

What you've described is essentially definition of a hash function.

So just use one and normalize results into range you want. Most basic case can use `GetHashCode`, but it is not guaranteed to produce the same results across different versions of framework.

Stable version that guarantees to provide exactly the same results across machines would be to use well known good hash - like crypto hash SHA256 and take several first bytes of result as integer and normalize. Crypto hash functions also conveniently take byte arrays as input so you can combine multiple values as bytes directly and get stable result.

```
    var intValue = 42;

    var bytesToHash = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
    var hash = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed.Create()
             .ComputeHash(bytesToHash);
    var toNormalize = BitConverter.ToUInt32(hash,0);
    var fancyRandom = (double)toNormalize/UInt32.MaxValue;
```

To combine multiple values into byte array you can either manually combine results of `BitConverter.GetBytes` or use `BinaryWriter` on `MemoryStream`.

Alternatively you can use resulting integer as seed for some custom implementation of pseudo-random generator (as one in .Net does not guarantee to provide same results across machines/version of .Net) as suggested in comments, but I don't think it will give significantly better distribution.

Note: make sure resulting numbers are distributed "randomly enough" for your case. Crypto hashing functions likely give result you want but I'm not sure how to prove that.

For "bonus" part: I would be very surprised if you can find pseudo-random generator that will consistently produce close results for "similar" seeds. Instead you can use same approach as above for separate parts - one that "same" and other that handles variation (i.e. `intValue & 0xFFFFFF00` for stable part, `intValue & 0xFF` for "small difference") and than combine resulting "random" numbers with some weight: `randomFromStable + 0.05 * randomFromDifference`.

Comment: Awesome, I'm looking all of that.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the hashcode (or something similar) as the seed to a `Random` object. Hashcodes must be the same for the same string so you will always get the same sequence back.

As Nuf notes, hashcodes are only guaranteed to be the same in the same app-domain; so it may not work across restarts.

As to your bonus point, getting there without writing your own RNG will be hard. Any variance in the seed can and should cause a lot of variation in the resulting sequence.